# How to find all the classes in a Object

Tags: python, class, object

I need to find all the classes and the relative value or string for a given object " EXAMPLE_1".

I tried with vars(obJ) but the result is not what I want since I need to find the name of the classes, then if it is "Operation" find again all the classes, if it's "Value" take the value inside it.

How can I loop inside the Object until the last argument is "Value"?

```
class Expression:
pass

class Operation(Expression):
    def __init__(self, op, arg1, arg2):
         self.op = op               # a string; always one of '+' '-' '*' '/'
         self.arg1 = arg1       # an Expression
         self.arg2 = arg2       # an Expression

class Value(Expression):
     def __init__(self, value):
     self.value = value # an integer; always positive

EXAMPLE_1 = Operation('*',Value(2),Operation('+',Value(5),Value(7)))
```

When I run the code

```
print(vars(EXAMPLE_1)) 
>>> {'op': '*', 'arg1': <__main__.Value object at 0x00000263B0D381D0>, 'arg2': <__main__.Operation object at 0x00000263B0D385F8>}
```

Comment: You want to print or compute ?

Comment: What result *do* you want? `Operation` is effectively a tree of expressions; you probably want a method that will walk that tree in a particular order.

Comment: The printing was an example, I need to compute since as @chepner wrote, I need to walk the tree in order to analyze each part of the class.

Comment: @Reznik, thanks but I cannot change the classes already defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple function that will iterate over the tree, producing operator symbols for `Operation` instances and values for `Value` instances.

```
def in_order_walk(expr):
    if isinstance(expr, Operation):
        yield from in_order_walk(expr.arg1)
        yield expr.op
        yield from in_order_walk(expr.arg2)
    elif isinstance(expr, Value):
        yield expr.value
```

An example of its use:

```
>>> list(in_order_walk(EXAMPLE_1))
[2, '*', 5, '+', 7]
```

However, `in_order_walk` would better be written as a method of the `Expression` class, to be overriden by subclasses, to avoid the need for explicit type sniffing.

```
class Expression:
    def in_order_walk(self):
        pass

class Operation(Expression):
    def __init__(self, op, arg1, arg2):
         self.op = op               # a string; always one of '+' '-' '*' '/'
         self.arg1 = arg1       # an Expression
         self.arg2 = arg2       # an Expression

    def in_order_walk(self):
        yield from self.arg1.in_order_walk()
        yield self.op
        yield from self.arg2.in_order_walk()

class Value(Expression):
     def __init__(self, value):
         self.value = value # an integer; always positive

     def in_order_walk(self):
         yield self.value
```

Then

```
>>> list(EXAMPLE_1.in_order_walk())
[2, '*', 5, '+', 7]
```

This approach is probably simpler as you expand your hierarchy. For instance, to handle operator precedence more cleanly, you would probably have separate classes for `+` and `*`.

Comment: Thanks! This works as I wanted! I just changed the yields [ op,arg1,arg2] in order to keep the original order ( prefix notation ) of the expression since I already wrote the function to convert from prefix to postfix/infix notation.

Comment: You can easily change `in_order_walk` to `pre_order_walk` by swapping the order of `yield from in_order_walk(expr.arg1)` and `yield expr.op`.

Answer (score 1):

Read about the `__repr__` function, there is a good explnation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr)

```py
class Expression:
    pass

class Operation(Expression):
    def __init__(self, op, arg1, arg2):
         self.op = op               # a string; always one of '+' '-' '*' '/'
         self.arg1 = arg1       # an Expression
         self.arg2 = arg2       # an Expression

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.arg1) + self.op + str(self.arg2)

class Value(Expression):
     def __init__(self, value):
         self.value = value # an integer; always positive

    def __repr__(self):
         return str(self.value)
```